# Running parcel bundler from command line doesn't stop the process

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, bundler, parceljs

I have a simple JS file that runs parcel bundler:

```js
const Bundler = require('parcel-bundler');
(async () => {
  const bundler = new Bundler('./src/index.html', {}); // options omitted for simplicity
  await bundler.bundle();
})();
```

I run it from CLI with:

```
node ./build.js
```

While bundler works fine and creates bundled files in the **`dist`** folder, the process never exits, but rather remains in the async loop.

I tried adding `then` callback or using return but none of it helped.
Using **`process.exit()`** would of course stop the process but would also limit me from chaining this command in the CI, which is the whole purpose.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to look into `bundler.on("buildEnd", ...)` or similar events? Do they get called?

Comment: Yes, build ends properly, I receive `Built in ...` message. Also if I use callback with console log I can see it being printed out. But node process never ends.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set `watch: false` in your options to let Parcel know it should not watch but just build it once.

The default option is `watch: true`, so whenever you change something in your files, Parcel will recognize the change and rebuild your application.